# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated in SoftLayer

Tags: ssl, openssl, tomcat7, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am accessing SoftLayer services but all of a sudden this error message was thrown out and all our services went down. Tried many methods online but none of which works. I guess it should be an expired SoftLayer certificated issue. Any comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That issue might be due to the TLS version you are currently using, there was a notification about this, check https://softlayer.github.io/release_notes/2018/20180301/ for more information, versions  1.0 and 1.1 will not be supported anymore as of this past March 1.

I recommend you to upgrade to Java8 as it has TLS 1.2 version by default, there are also ways to set TLS versions to 1.2 or higher in java 7, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but this is exactly the issue I am hitting. I was aware of the notification mentioned above and corrected the api-deprecated.softlayer.com accordingly. It worked for quite a few days until three days ago when nothing worked at all.

I can't do JAVA 8 since my software stack is built on top of Grails 2.x which is not compatible with JAVA 8. Trying to figure out a way to enable TLSv1.2 in JAVA 7 but seems not easy. I know Jdk1.7_131-b31 has a support for TLSv1.2 but that needs special support from Oracle (Not public available). Any other suggestions?

Comment: I suspect it might be an SSL certificate that I am using to communicate with SoftLayer has expired, but there is no document from Softlayer online where I can check for help. For example, this webpage has no content at all.

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/ssl-certificates